# How to create a secure Contact Form (cf) using CodeIgniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, contacts

I want to create secure cf using CodeIgniter. I'm new to using CodeIgniter. Is their some library which I should use or should I create one with FormHelper and EmailHelper. Also, if I go with creating one with Helpers, how can spams be taken care of?

Comment: You should make your question clearer. How do you want to secure it? What should be secured? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CIs form helper will automatically escape any data submitted to secure it, although you can specify additional functions/purifying etc by using the [form validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

ie

`$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|xss|trim');`

as well as custom call back functions.

As for spam, you can use the built in CAPTCHA library, which generally is "ok" but not fantastic. There's plenty of documentation out there to help you implement RECAPTCHA instead.

In short you'll want the Form Helper, Form Validation Library, Email Helper and possibly the captcha plugin or an extension.